# About the formal disk

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Let be the formal disc the spectrum of the $\mathbb{K}[[t]]$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is the field of real numbers or complex numbers

Now, if we see it as topological space with Zariski's topology, it is a natural manifold? Or, exists a standard way to equip it with a manifold's structure?
thanks

Comment: You probably don't want the Zariski topology, which has too few open sets.  The formal disk also has too few points if you regard it as a topological space in a naive way.  It seems that what you're looking for is a complex analyticification (as in GAGA), but I don't know a reference for formal schemes.  Other possible search terms: rigid analytic geometry, Berkovich spaces, adic spaces, etc.